# Did not went undisputed or go undisputed?

Tags: sentence-meaning

May i know which is correct:

```
This claim did not went undisputed or this claim did not go undisputed?
```

I wrote the former in my word doc but the auto-correct function suggested that 'went' be replaced with 'go'.

Comment: For questions such as this, you have only to google the phrases **did not go** and **did not went** to find numerous sites that will give you the answer.

Comment: I've downvoted and flagged this question because it **clearly lacks research**.

Answer (score 0):

And rightly so.

Where you use the auxilliary "do" or "did" the verb which follows is - to all intents - an infinitive. So that is the form that you use.